# Adding an additional Inner join with mutiple tables SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, inner-join, ssrs-2012

I'm wondering how to inner join customer name-(CUSTNAM) from table rm001 to this query & have it added to my SSRS Report. Could use help adding this. Thanks

I've tried adding after the "from" saleslineitems as an "and" but it broke the SSRS report.

```html
use n

select distinct  a.[SOP Number]
--, [Item Number]
,  a.[Customer Number], a.[Created Date from Sales Transaction], a.[Primary Shipto Address Code from Sales Line Item]
, a.[City from Sales Transaction], 
,c.city
,case
     when b.CITY <> c.city then 'Cities Do Not Match'
     when c.city = '' then 'Cities do not Match'
     when isnull(c.city,'1') = '1' then 'Cities Do Not Match'
     else ''
end as [validate cities]
,b.USERDEF1 as GP_F
, c.f_number as EZ_F
,case 
     when b.USERDEF1 <> c.f_number then 'Fs do not Match'
     when b.USERDEF1 = '' then 'No F in GP'
     
     else ''
end as [validate Fs]
, c.f_expiration
,case
     when c.f_expiration <= getdate() then ' F EXPIRED '     
     when c.f_expiration <= DATEADD(d,15,getDate()) then 'F expiring soon'
     --when c.f_expiration >= dateAdd(d,61,getdate()) then 'valid F Expiration'
     else ''
end as [valid f date]

--,( select top(1) c.f_number from NBS_BoundBook..contacts where c.f_number = b.userdef1 order by c.uid desc )
--, a.* 
from SalesLineItems a
inner join rm00102 b on a.[customer number] = b.CUSTNMBR and a.[Primary Shipto Address Code from Sales Line Item] = b.ADRSCODE 

left join NBS_BoundBook..contacts c  on Replace(Replace(ltrim(rtrim(b.USERDEF1)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = 
( select top(1) Replace(Replace(ltrim(rtrim(c.f_number)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') from NBS_BoundBook..contacts 
     where Replace(Replace(ltrim(rtrim(c.f_number)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = Replace(Replace(ltrim(rtrim(b.USERDEF1)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
     and c.city= b.CITY order by c.uid desc )
where [sop type] = 'Order'
and [Created Date from Sales Transaction] >= dateAdd(d,-3, getDate())
and [Item Tracking Option] in ( 'Serial Numbers' )
order by a.[Customer Number]
```

Comment: Just a few comments: Alias columns used in tables.  fully qualify where clause filter columns.  If any filter value is sourced from `c` the left join will behave like an inner join and the null values generated from the left join will be excluded because NULL will not be equal to that filter value.  You should show what you tried to do as well so we can address where you went wrong and you can learn from that!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
    .....
FROM SalesLineItems a
    INNER JOIN rm00102 b
        ON a.[customer number] = b.CUSTNMBR
            AND a.[Primary Shipto Address Code from Sales Line Item] = b.ADRSCODE
    INNER JOIN rm001 cust
    ON cust.[customer number] = a.[customer number]
    LEFT JOIN NBS_BoundBook..contacts c
....
```